# Statement text object in vim

Tags: vim, read-eval-print-loop

With Vim 8's new terminal feature `:term`, tmux is no more needed when using an interactive console. While using the [sendtoterm](https://github.com/habamax/vim-sendtoterm) plugin to send code to the Vim term window, I noticed that I miss a "statement text object" in Vim. Often I have code like this:

```
p = plot(xlims=(0,107), ylims=[0,107], 
         grid=false,
         label="", legend=true)
vline!([107], label="", color=:black, linestyle=:dot)
```

where I just want to execute the first command, but not the second. In addition, the first statement has linebreaks in it. So sending just a line, as well as a whole paragraph does not work in this case, making it necessary to visually select the statement and send this selection. What I want is a statement textobject, which can be called with tS and that would only send:

```
p = plot(xlims=(0,107), ylims=[0,107], 
         grid=false,
         label="", legend=true)
```

Is there such an textobject already, that works for most programming languages or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Im not aware of a builtin that does this. It would be incredibly difficult to do universally, since each language is so different. (And some dont even have “statements”—looking at you, lisp.) one could conceivably build a plugin which enables filetype-specific callbacks to be registered that can do the appropriate textobject selection though. Otoh, it might require deep AST knowledge for each language. (Man oh man do i hope we get a tree-sitter in vim.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a sufficient solution to my own question which works for the example above and also even for "for loops" if `match.it` is used and being on the first line: `V%`. So mapping a text object or directly the command to this visual selection works for my use case. But more sophesticated solutions are appreciated.